# Hadoop Reducer execution re-occurrence

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

So the Mapper gets executed only once on a given slave node containing a given data block, correct?

But the Reducer may execute multiple times because the same key may originate from many Mapper nodes, correct?

Also is it correct that the Shuffle and Sort will occur on each Mapper for a single MapReduce job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, I don't think it's proper to say how many times Mapper/Reducer are executed because they are widely distributed into different nodes and scheduled by JobTracker in MRv1 or ResourceManager in MRv2. But hopefully my answers below could help you have a better understanding.

Q: *"So the Mapper gets executed only once on a given slave node containing a given data block, correct?"*

A: Correct in most case. Normally, hadoop will launch a mapper for each input split (which has the same size as a data block by default), but it will start a new one if there is a mapper failed.

Q: *"But the Reducer may execute multiple times because the same key may originate from many Mapper nodes, correct?"*

A: Not correct. Shuffle and Sort process will merge all mappers output into a single sorted input and feed to reducer. The number of reducer is defined by user.

Q: *"Also is it correct that the Shuffle and Sort will occur on each Mapper for a single MapReduce job?"*

A: Inaccurate. Shuffle phase is process hadoop performed to sort and transfer the mappers' outputs to reducers as inputs. When all the mappers' outputs have been copied, Sort phase will merge all outputs and maintain their sort order. So technically first part of Shuffle and Sort happens for each mapper.

Thanks